# Date format in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have order time and order date
I want to combine them together and make it in the correct format like this

`2020-06-18T21:51:10+08:00`
what is the meaning of T? and the api im dealing with wont work without this format

order_time: 12:21 pm

order_date: 2020-06-19

I tried with this but i need it to be combined in `datetime` format

```
$asapTime  = date("h:i a", strtotime($order_time));
$printDate  = date("Y-m-d ", strtotime($order_date));
```

Comment: I added an answer, you can remove extra space to get your expected value

Comment: T actually means that the time is in UST format. It is not some kind of placeholder.

Comment: `T` - Timezone abbreviations (Examples: EST, MDT). If you need just `T` instead of abbreviations  then tell me. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps :

```
$time  = date("h:i a", strtotime($order_time));
$date  = date("Y-m-d ", strtotime($order_date));
$timestamp1 = date('Y-m-dTH:i:sO', strtotime("$date $time"));
$timestamp2 = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', strtotime("$date $time")); // If you need T instead of abbreviations
```

Output :

```
$timestamp1 = "2020-06-19CEST07:58:00+0200"
$timestamp2 = "2020-06-19T08:06:00+0200"
```